# Plus sign after a number means?

Tags: inequality

This maybe a stupid question but if I suffix a plus sign (+) after a number, it means at least?I mean, 5000+ means atleast 5000 but it doesn't mean more than 5000, right? Because to 
indicate a possibility of more than you use the more than sign (>).

So, 5000+ = Atleast 5000 but not necessarily more than 5000

Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Mathematicians rarely use this notation because it is unclear exactly what is meant.  Using it in an informal non-mathematical context is OK but you shouldn't use it if you are doing math.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"At least 5000" means 5000 or more.

If you have 6000 bananas, you have at least 5000 bananas, and in fact, you have more than 5000 bananas.

"5000+" is casual shorthand for "at least 5000", "5000 or more", or "some quantity $x$ such that $x \ge 5000$."

5000+ is not considered the be a standard mathematical notation. It is a common but informal nomenclature that is used for convenience. Note that 5000- is never used, and -5000 has a different meaning entirely.

Comment: Another example may be when they write "18+" on something, meaning you should be 18 or older to smoke/drink/play/watch this something :)

Answer (score 2):

In expressions like $\lim\limits_{x\to1+}$, it means the number $1$ is being approached from above rather than from both sides.

But in some other context, it has the meaning suggested in the question.